# How do I solve $ \int \frac{e^x}{ 1+e^{2x}}\, dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, substitution

So... I have been struggling with this expression  $$\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}$$ for a while now... I allways seem to get into a loop and can't get out!

Example:
I substitute $u=e^x$ and then get $du= e^x  du$. So the new expression looks like this --> $$\frac{1}{1+u^2} \cdot du$$ . After this I substitute $m=u^2$ and get $$dm = 2u \cdot  du.$$ So the new expression looks like this -> $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{m}(1+m)}$$..
After this Im stuck and can't get out.. I have tried to substitute other expressions first in u but still I end up somewhat simmilar to this situation!

Please can someone explain me what am I doing wrong! Can someone evaluate this expression for me showing me the steps?! I would be greatful!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**    $$\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}du=\arctan(u)$$

Comment: It's a good answer, don't get me wrong, but how is this a hint? If I ask you "what is $2+2$", then "$4$" is not a hint, it's a solution. And what you gave is not a hint, but a solution...

Comment: Yes, this answer needs more information.  Perhaps telling Grass that this answer shows he cannot do his problem in a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

What's the derivative of $\arctan(u)$?